# How to concat to values from two select statements

Tags: sql

I want to concat group name with the number of the students of the group with another parameter to select groups from Groups table
Like this  :

```
Group1  --  250 std
Group2  --  243 std
```

Groups and students are separated tables and foreign key in Groups table used to select target groups
I have a two tables one of them has std data with group Id as foreign key and groups table has groups data and a foreign key for subject 
I need to get all the groups which coresponding with subject id I want and count the std of each group ,concat it with the group name

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Tag your question with the database you are really using.  Sample data and desired results are also helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about SQL Joins here

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

A join retrieves columns from different tables by relating two rows using an ON clause

Comment: Did you try this @Abdallah

Comment: Not satisfy what I want all what I want is to retrieve some records from a table and the number of corresponding records of another table